# Find string and append another string at end of the line in unix

Tags: unix

I have a file in the follwing format.

```
111286,QWER ,ABCD ,AKL ,A/C ,L ,NZLC ,xyz@msn.com ,+6421365188 ,QN ,All , 
111278,TATA ,BATMAN ,AKL ,CFA ,L ,NZLC , ,00000006672 ,QN ,All ,
```

Need to search a first word and append a new word to the end of the line as follws

if search pattern is `111286` and new word is `MDW` then the result would be

```
111286,HAYDEN ,FERGUSSON ,AKL ,A/C ,L ,NZLC ,Dr1fty@msn.com ,+6421365188 ,QN ,All ,MDW,
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using **sed**:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.*\)111288\(.*\)$/\1111288\2MDW,/g' /path/to/your-file
```

If you only want to match the start of the line, then it'll look like

```
sed -e 's/^111288\(.*\)$/111288\1MDW,/g' /path/to/your-file
```

You can add a comma after the pattern if you don't want to match both `11128` and `111288`

```
sed -e 's/^111288,\(.*\)$/111288,\1MDW,/g' /path/to/your-file
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed '/111286/s/ $/MDW,/' foo.txt
```

result

```
111286,QWER ,ABCD ,AKL ,A/C ,L ,NZLC ,xyz@msn.com ,+6421365188 ,QN ,All ,MDW,
111278,TATA ,BATMAN ,AKL ,CFA ,L ,NZLC , ,00000006672 ,QN ,All ,
```

- search for `111286`
- replace end of line with `MDW,`